# Possibility of representing the Möbius strip by ways other than specifying a parameterization?

Tags: manifolds, graphing-functions, locus, mobius-band

I have looked up some texts, they all represent the Möbius strip by ways of specifying a parameterization. This is the only way how the Möbius strip is represented founded in the Wikipedia currently.

**Question 1:**

Can the Möbius strip be represented as the **graph** of a map?

For example, a map $\phi$ from a subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is specified, and the Möbius strip is exactly of the form $\{(V,\phi(V)) : V$ $\in$ $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \}$, which is called the **graph** of $\phi$.

**Question 2:**

Can the Möbius strip be represented as the **locus** defined by constraint equations? (With restrictions on allowable range of the variables.)

For example, an equation $f(X)=0$ is specified, where $X$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $f$ map $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and the Möbius strip is exactly of the form $\{X \in \mathbb{R}^3 : f(X)=0 \}$, which is called the **locus** defined by the constraint equation $f(X)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Neither kind of representation is possible, because the Möbius strip is not orientable.

Suppose $M$ is a regular level set of a smooth function $F: U \to \mathbb R$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$.  (A ***regular level set*** in this context is a level set on which the gradient of $F$ does not vanish.) Then $\operatorname{grad} f$ is a nowhere-vanishing normal vector field along $M$, so $M$ must be orientable.

Similarly, suppose $M$ is the graph of a smooth function $f: V\to \mathbb R$, where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$.  Then $M$ is a regular level set of the function $F(x,y,z)= z-f(x,y)$, so again $M$ must be orientable.

Answer (score -2):

Since the Möbius strip does not live in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the first is not possible. 
To have it as a function $f(x,y,z)=0$see:

$$-R^2y+x^2y+y^3-2Rxz-2x^2z-2y^2z+yz^2=0.$$

I copied it from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusStrip.html
trula

Comment: I am unsure I am able to figure out what do you mean in the 1st line.

Comment: Graphs of real-valued functions in two real variables don’t live in $\mathbb{R}^2$, they live in $\mathbb{R}^3$ — as does the Möbius strip. Why is the first impossible?

Comment: my error, sorry